# How to create simply REST API Login?

Tags: mysql, rest, authentication, postman, codeigniter-3

I've trying to create login code in REST Server and while I use POSTMAN to check it, the output always show HTTP_BAD_REQUEST(Login Failed). *The code is ignoring security.*

I use REST from https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

[image]

**This is My Controller**

```
public function index_post(){

        $data_memb = array(
            'id_member'=>$this->post('id_member'),
            'password'=>$this->post('password')
        );

        $result = $this->Member_model_api->loginMember($data_memb);

        if ($result == TRUE) {
            $this->response([
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'Login Successfull'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
        } else {
            $this->response([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'Login Failed'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }            
    }
}
```

**This is My Model**

```
public function loginMember($data_memb)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM member WHERE id_member = ?';
    $binds = array($data_memb['id_member']);
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $binds);

    if ($query->num_rows()>0) {
        $rw_password = $query->result();
        if (password_verify($data_memb['password'], 
            $rw_password[0]->password)) {

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }        
}
```

I expect the output is HTTP_OK(Login Successfull), or if you have more reference code, please tell me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe  the content-type is wrong.

Comment: @jin what the right ?,

Comment: now this is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.try multipart/form-data or application/json

Comment: I've tried it, but still have same output like first

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `POST` method, you should use `form-data` while sending request.

I assume there may be some re-formatting issue on the server-side which might be preventing your login functionality to get verified.

Try printing both variables on the server-side and view the output.

```
var_dump($data_memb)
```

Nothing needs to send `urlencoded` in `POST` request.

Try changing the request type and see, this will work.

Comment: I tried it and the var_dump is return value from id_member and password has I insert, but why the message still show "Login Failed"?, still confuse

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, put exit(); after var_dump(), If it shows blank, means your variable is not available in post data.

Comment: Also, have you changed request to form-data? If not, do it as well.

Comment: after put exit(); the output show array id_member and password, thats mean is successfully ?, I do it in form-data